# the order of adjectives

Tags: adjective-order

the order of adjectives is like this: **size> style> color**

For instance, long curly black hair

but I ran into this one in a book : dark curly hair

Is it also correct?

Comment: This 'order of adjectives' thing is not a hard-and-fast rule, just guidance.

Comment: Your list is a bit short. A longer list is opinion, size, age, shape, colour, origin, material, purpose. So curly black hair. But writers make errors or ignore, or are unaware of, 'rules'.

Comment: 'Curly black hair' sounds perfectly good to me.